# Untracked files between branches in Git

Tags: git, branch

I've been searching around here for to look for an answer and it seems I may just be making incorrect assumptions on how git branches are supposed to work.

I have my `master` branch and I've created a feature branch called `profiles` where I'm doing some specific work to profiles. While working on profiles I've changed 5 or 6 files and added another 5 or 6 new files. I needed to switch back to the `master` branch to fix a quick bug and noticed all the new files and modified files where in there as well. I guess this makes sense since git isnt going to remove untracked files from the `master` branch and bring them back for my `profiles` branch since they are, in fact, untracked. But what about the changes to existing files. Why are they showing up in the master branch.

Whats the best practice here. I'm not ready to commit the changes locally yet. Should I just be stashing all these changes, switch to `master`, make the small fix, switch back to `profiles` then reapply the stash?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> "I'm not ready to commit the changes locally yet."

Commits in git are local things that can be undone, redone and re-re-done at will.  It's only when you push the commit somewhere that you need to pay attention.

Plus, commits are visible to local tools like `gitk`, and can have diffs taken of them and can be rebased onto other commits, etc.  It's a very powerful tool.  Learn to use it.

I frequently do:

```
git add .; git commit -a -m 'WIP'
```

just to stash away everything in the current work tree if I think I might be interrupted.  If I make a few more changes, I use:

```
git add .; git commit --amend
```

to update my "WIP" commit in-place.  When I'm finally ready for the real commit, I just:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~; git reset
```

and now I can carefully control what the final commit will be.

Comment: I have a horrible memory and like to use git to see where I am on my work (and with magit its even easier, and is incorporated in to my workflow). Really, you solution makes more sense though. Just commit more often. Just need to tweak my workflow a bit. thanks

Comment: Just for clarification, is there any intended difference between `git reset --soft HEAD~; git reset` and `git reset HEAD^` ?  As far as I can see they both reset HEAD and the index to the parent of the "WIP" commit ready to make a real commit using some or all of the working tree changes but I may have missed a subtlety.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: "--soft does not touch the index file nor the working tree at all, but requires them to be in a good order. This leaves all your changed files "Changes to be committed", as git status would put it." if you use "git reset HEAD^" you won't get this fatal: Cannot do a soft reset in the middle of a merge.

Comment: When I wrote this answer, "the stash" was a relatively new thing. But I'm now thoroughly embracing the use of "git stash …" to save and restore work in progress, even programmatically.  For example, "git stash; git pull --ff-only; git stash pop --index" can be done with almost no chance of needing intervention, and yet it keeps me up to date with upstream.

Answer (score 8):

They're not showing up in the master branch - if you did a hard reset and a clean, they'd disappear. Git is merely preserving your local modifications when you switch branches.

This is commonly useful; you might have realized you want to commit those modifications to a different branch than the one you're currently on. If the modifications conflicted with the difference between the two branches, git would refuse to switch branches.

You're right about the best approach, though - switching branches cleanly is in my experience one of the most common uses of `git stash`.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you created the branch with `git branch profiles`, but didn't switch to it, so you stayed in `master`, and it got the file changes when you did a commit.

After creating the branch, you need to explicitly switch to it with `git checkout` (or you can just create new branch on-the-fly and switch to it in one step using `git checkout -b` ).

If you have changes you don't want to lose (or commit to the current branch), but instead put into the other branch, do:

```
git add -A
git stash
git checkout <other branch>
git stash pop
```

More info on `git stash` is available from [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing)