# Adding new files to a GIT branch shows the file in master branch as well?

Tags: git, branch

I am attempting to use GIT locally with Visual Studio 2015 community.  When creating a new branch and making changes to files I can switch back and forth and GIT keeps everything separate as expected. When I add a new file to a branch, however, and switch back to the master branch, the new file is also listed in the solution. How does one keep new files in the branch until the merge takes place? My master is production, with dev happening in the branch.

Answer (score 3):

Git never cares about untracked files. When you add a file, and before you commit it, it is untracked. It doesn't belong in *any* branch.

Once you commit it to a branch you will see the behaviour you are expecting.

There are many other questions about this on Stack Overflow, e.g. [Untracked files between branches in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187000/untracked-files-between-branches-in-git).